# React-Native-Maps how to draw polylines From Array List?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I've started using https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps and having no luck drawing polylines from an array of array coordinates on the map.

I am not sure if I'm passing in the array of coordinates correctly.

this is how I am rendering the polyline:

Here is api link that contains coords: https://run.mocky.io/v3/e42d76ce-2ac8-4199-9f2c-e5b611960d38

I have code like this.

```
 <MapView
            style={styles.mapStyle}
            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
            minZoomLevel={0}
            showsTraffic={false}
            showsBuildings={true}
            followUserLocation={false}
            loadingEnabled={true}
            showsUserLocation={true}
            loadingIndicatorColor={'green'}
            initialRegion={{
              latitude: 37.78825,
              longitude: -122.4324,
              latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
              longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
            }}
            zoomEnabled={true}
            showsUserLocation={true}>
              {
                
                
              speed.map((d) =>
              d.segments.map((c) => (
                <Polyline
                  coordinates={c.coordinate}
                  strokeColor="#000" the map-provider
         
                  strokeWidth={6}>
                  <Marker
                    coordinate={{latitude: 37.8025259, longitude: -122.4351431}}
                    title="Flatiron School Atlanta"
                    description="This is where the magic happens!"></Marker>
                </Polyline>
              )),
            )}
          </MapView>
```

and i have coordinates like this,

```
{"coordinates":[[43.43522206128157,-79.73892179139867],[43.43522206128157,-79.73892179139867],[43.43522206128157,-79.73892179139867],[43.43522206128157,-79.73892179139867],[43.43522206128157,-79.73892179139867],[43.43522206128157,-79.73892179139867],[43.43522206128157,-79.73892179139867],[43.43522206128157,-79.73892179139867],[43.43522206128157,-79.73892179139867],[43.43522206128157,-79.73892179139867],[43.43522206128157,-79.73892179139867],[43.43522206128157,-79.73892179139867],[43.43522206128157,-79.73892179139867],[43.43522206128157,-79.73892179139867]]}
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

coordinates in [Polyline](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/polyline.md) is an array of LatLng

> type LatLng {   latitude: Number,   longitude: Number, }

So something like this should work:

```
d.segments.map((c) => 
    <Polyline
      coordinates={c.coordinates.map(c => ({latitude: c[0], longitude: c[1]}))}
      strokeColor="#000"
      strokeWidth={6}>
    </Polyline>
)
```